# The batch job that changes Income Timing every new quarter is not working

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

**Controller:**

```
global class QuarterlyRollupBatch implements Database.batchable<Opportunity> {
    Public Date lastDateOfThisQuarter,fiscalYearStartDate,firstDateOfNextQuarter;
    Public Integer quarter;

    global Iterable<Opportunity>  start(Database.BatchableContext info) { 

        Integer FiscalYearStartMonth = 1;// [select FiscalYearStartMonth from Organization where id=:Userinfo.getOrganizationId()].FiscalYearStartMonth;

        Date todaydate = system.today();
        fiscalYearStartDate = date.newinstance(system.today().year(), FiscalYearStartMonth, 1);
        quarter = ((system.today().month() - FiscalYearStartMonth) / 3) + 1;

        Integer addMonths = quarter * 3;

        lastDateOfThisQuarter = fiscalYearStartDate;
        //Date closeDate = [Select EndDate From Period Where type = 'Quarter' and StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER].EndDate;

        // this is the last date of the current quarter
        lastDateOfThisQuarter = lastDateOfThisQuarter.addMonths(addMonths).addDays(-1);
        firstDateOfNextQuarter=lastDateOfThisQuarter.addDays(1);
        System.debug('@@@ '+firstDateOfNextQuarter);

        List<Opportunity> oppList=[select id,name,Est_Syndication_Completion_Date__c,income_Timing__c,Owner.Name from Opportunity where  Est_Syndication_Completion_Date__c <: firstDateOfNextQuarter and Est_Syndication_Completion_Date__c >=: todaydate and income_Timing__c='Future Opportunity'];

        system.debug('Opplist'+oppList); 
        return oppList;      
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Opportunity> oppList) {
        if (oppList.size() > 0) {
            for( Opportunity o:oppList) {            
                o.income_Timing__c = 'Current Opportunity';
            }
            update oppList;
        }    
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){ }
}


global class QuarterlyRollupBatchsch implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        Integer FiscalYearStartMonth = [select FiscalYearStartMonth from Organization where id=:Userinfo.getOrganizationId()].FiscalYearStartMonth;
        Integer Currentmonth = Date.Today().Month(); 

        QuarterlyRollupBatch createquarterupdate= new QuarterlyRollupBatch();
        if(currentmonth==FiscalYearStartMonth || math.mod(Currentmonth,3)==1) {
            database.executebatch(createquarterupdate,100);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors.  Was it working at one time and now not working.  Need some more details beyond just the code itself to try to help.

Comment: I am not getting errors.It is working in dev sandbox. Here i didn't schedule any jobs in dev.Just through developer console i tested it.It is working.

Comment: Well then the title of the question is very misleading.  It ends with 'is not working'.  I don't understand what you are asking for then.